# How to pregmatch youtube url with the youtube short url and get videoids from them php

Tags: php, youtube

Hi am trying to pregmatch youtube urls and youtube shorten url and get video ids from am able to pregmatch the youtube url but unable to pregmatch short url
Here is my code..

```
 if (preg_match('@^(?:https://(?:www\\.)?youtube.com/)(watch\\?v=|v/)([a-zA-Z0-9_]*)@', $video_id, $match))
```

where videoid= https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Xt4S-Ot0Jcs
How can I pregmatch short url like https://youtu.be/Xt4S-Ot0Jcs how can I get the videoids from both using php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with a simpler regex if you just want to get the videoId :

```
if (preg_match('@(youtube\.com/watch\?v=|youtu\.be/)([a-zA-Z0-9_]*)@', $video_id, $match))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public function get_id($url)
{
    $ytshorturl = 'youtu.be/';
    $ytlongurl = 'www.youtube.com/watch?v=';
    if (strpos($url, $ytshorturl) !== false) {
        $url = str_replace($ytshorturl, $ytlongurl, $url);
    }
    $components = parse_url($url);
    parse_str($components['query'], $results);
    return $results['v'];
}
```

$url = "https://youtu.be/oeg192rQ1xE"; //sample url

echo "Id is : ". get_id($url);

Comment: Hi and thanks for the answer. Your answer would be much more valuable to us if you added an explanation about what your code does and why it helps the OP

Comment: You need to pass your url to $url and call get_id function with parameter named $url.
FInally output should be like this.
Id is : oeg192rQ1xE